# How to handle different customer version in angular app

Tags: html, angular, typescript, multi-tenant

I'm new to angular and working on an angular app which will have multiple customers. Different customers may need different customisation in both view and functionality. I need to avoid maximum if else conditions and ngIf etc. as it will affect the code complexity. So is there any solution that will help on this.

I have gone through Google but couldn't find any optimal approach.

Comment: if some features are pieces of ui - you can't do much except for if+else. if differencies are some service logic implementations - you can use DI to provide one or another piece  as a replacement. generally it depends...

Comment: Your question is very generic. What comes to my mind are things like Angular Material Themes for visual adjustments or Angular Routing with guards, so that a customer can only enter specific components, if he has the rights to...